# Place VC Post Grid anywhere in theme templates. Assistance needed

Tags: javascript

#### I wanna place a featured posts carousel right after the header and I figured I would use visual composer for that since I can build the grid to my liking but it proved a little difficult since VC has some limitations such as integration of the shortcodes anywhere in the theme and getting them executed.

First someone suggested to create a page with the shortcode in it, go to the page, access page source, copy the code and place wherever I want. It was simple and it worked only to discover later that while it shows in Firefox it vanishes in Chrome but I found somewhere this solution:

adding `add_filter('vc_grid_get_grid_data_access','__return_true');` which solved the problem, now it displays both Chrome and Firefox.

I figured I would do the same for other pages such as forum and groups and others but it didn't work. It returns nothing. I figured since there are mo other post grids on the page it's not gonna call the js file. Sorry if I don't speak your language, I have a little basic knowledge about some things which allowed me to achieve things through trials and errors most of the time.

Now I've identified the exact snippet from the vc-basic-grid.php file that executes vc_grid.min.js and allows for the post grid to be displayed. Only that is not happening when the placing the code wherever in the theme templates.

The snippet is:

```
public function shortcodeScripts() {
    parent::shortcodeScripts();

    wp_register_script( 'vc_grid-js-imagesloaded', vc_asset_url( 'lib/bower/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' ) );
    wp_register_script( 'vc_grid', vc_asset_url( 'js/dist/vc_grid.min.js' ), array(
            'jquery',
            'underscore',
            'vc_pageable_owl-carousel',
            'waypoints',
            //'isotope',
            'vc_grid-js-imagesloaded',
        ), WPB_VC_VERSION, true );
}

public function enqueueScripts() {
    parent::enqueueScripts();
    wp_enqueue_script( 'vc_grid-js-imagesloaded' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'vc_grid' );
}

public static function addExcludedId( $id ) {
    self::$excluded_ids[] = $id;
}

public static function excludedIds() {
    return self::$excluded_ids;
}
```

How do I integrate this code into my forum page for the following code to be executed.

```
<!-- vc_grid start -->
<div class="vc_grid-container-wrapper vc_clearfix">
<div class="vc_grid-container vc_clearfix wpb_content_element vc_basic_grid vc_custom_1479903767331 featured" data-initial-loading-animation="fadeIn" data-vc-grid-settings="{&quot;page_id&quot;:2894,&quot;style&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;vc_get_vc_grid_data&quot;,&quot;shortcode_id&quot;:&quot;%7B%22tag%22%3A%22vc_basic_grid%22%2C%22atts%22%3A%7B%22post_type%22%3A%22post%22%2C%22max_items%22%3A%226%22%2C%22element_width%22%3A%222%22%2C%22gap%22%3A%220%22%2C%22item%22%3A%222904%22%2C%22grid_id%22%3A%22vc_gid%3A1479927728768-be91949c-4e72-1%22%2C%22taxonomies%22%3A%2247%22%2C%22css%22%3A%22.vc_custom_1479903767331%7Bmargin-top%3A+0px+%21important%3Bmargin-right%3A+0px+%21important%3Bmargin-bottom%3A+0px+%21important%3Bmargin-left%3A+0px+%21important%3Bpadding-top%3A+0px+%21important%3Bpadding-right%3A+0px+%21important%3Bpadding-bottom%3A+0px+%21important%3Bpadding-left%3A+0px+%21important%3B%7D%22%2C%22el_class%22%3A%22featured%22%7D%2C%22content%22%3A%22%22%7D&quot;,&quot;tag&quot;:&quot;vc_basic_grid&quot;}" data-vc-request="http://www.blogfort.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" data-vc-post-id="2894" data-vc-public-nonce="2a7dd9bb6a">
    </div>
</div><!-- vc_grid end -->
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I noticed you got quite a wall of text there, which is good, as it shows that you put some effort in writing this question, but it'll scare off a good portion of the people trying to help you. So here are some tips: 1. Keep the question as short as possible, without leaving out necessary information 2. If your question gets that long anyway, put some captions in there to help people navigate your question.

Comment: I'll try do that. Thank you.

Comment: I thought I could cut more from it but it's vital to explain what my problem is exactly :(

Comment: No problem, just add some captions (they start with `#`, `##` ..., depending on what size you want them to be).